# Javascript GetElementByID has no value

Tags: javascript, jquery

My form ID is "requestquote".  When I submit the form I am receiving an error in the console that  ('formSub has no value').  The form process is being completed via my PHP action file but I need this bit of javascript to run as well.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<script> 
_opt.push(['instrument','requestquote']);

var formSub = $('requestquote');
console.log(formSub);

formSub.submit(function(){

_opt.modifyFormParameters = function(parameters){

parameters["_orig_action"] = document.getElementById("_orig_action").value;
parameters["_opt_vid"] = document.getElementById("_opt_vid").value;
parameters["_opt_visit"] = document.getElementById("_opt_visit").value;
parameters["_opt_cid"] = document.getElementById("_opt_cid").value;
parameters["_opt_url"] = document.getElementById("_opt_url").value;
parameters["_opt_paget"] = document.getElementById("_opt_paget").value;
parameters["first_name"] = document.getElementById("name").value;
parameters["company"] = document.getElementById("company").value;
parameters["website"] = document.getElementById("url").value;
parameters["email"] = document.getElementById("email").value;
parameters["phone"] = document.getElementById("phone").value;

return parameters;
};
_opt.push(['submit', 'requestquote']);
_opt.the_form = this;

setTimeout(function(){ _opt.the_form.submit(); } , 1000);
return false;
});
</script>
```

Here is the Form Code

```
<form id="requestquote" action="/quote-process/contact_pr_EPH.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Make sure to run this after defining the element in HTML. Other than that there's not enough information.

Comment: can you please add the code of the `<form>`?

Comment: The script is the last thing within the body in footer.php

Comment: I think you need to provide a *complete* minimal test case that fully demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Wait, you write that you get an error _when you submit the form_. That would suggest that the problem is somewhere _inside_ the onsubmit handler. I think you'll need to show us more code if you want us to be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's the ID of the form then it should be :

`$('#requestquote');` or even `$('form#requestquote');`.

`$()` does more than just `GetElementByID`.
Read up on the jQuery (truly Sizzle) selector(s):  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: So obvious and yet so hard to detect ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by one of:

- Not having an element with the given id in the document at all
- Not having an element with the given id in the document at the time the script is run (e.g. when the `<script>` appears before the `<form>` in the source order)

You can deal with timing issues by rearranging the source order, or by wrapping the gEbId call in a function that gets called onload / ondomready / otherwise after the form element exists.

Comment: I have added an on page load jQuery function .. still receiving null for 'formSub'.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the example code. But could the JavaScript be executing before the `requestquote` element has been made?

Something like an `onLoad` event can be used to make the JavaScript execute after all the HTML elements have loaded.

Comment: He already told that "The script is the last thing within the body in footer.php"...

Answer (score 0):

In the third line of your script, `var formSub = $('requestquote');` should be `var formSub = $('#requestquote');`

The # indicates to jQuery that you want to search for an id rather than a tag name.